# Google Analytics not Tracking

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

I cannot get Google Analytics to track my website. It keeps saying tracking not installed, when clearly, it is. I put it in the header like it says too. Site Link [Here](http://www.therac.net)

```
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-42551225-1', 'therac.net');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereas Google Webmaster Tool validates live, you may wait a few hours (1 day max) to see your first analytics in Google Analytics. Don't worry, your first visits will be tracked even if Google Analytics keep saying the tracking code is not installed.

Have a good day !

Comment: I had to wait even more than one day. Your code seems right, I suppose you copied it from GA console.

Answer (score 0):

You should see pageviews in the "Realtime" reports. Standard reports will take much longer.

Also, this is the code snippet for Google Universal Analytics (the new version). Is your property set up with universal or standard analytics?